# Thmtools get rid of a dot

Tags: boxes, thmtools

I'm using thmtools for my LaTeX Template. I often use the numbered math boxes. But now I wanted to add the same Box just without the math context. So I build this:

```
\documentclas{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
% The Box
\declaretheorem[name = , numbered = no,]{Boxname}
\newenvironment{boxname}[1][]{
    \begin{Boxname}\ifblank{#1}{}{\color{black}\hspace*{-0.68em}\normalfont\textbf{#1}}\color{black}\normalfont$ $\newline
        \raisebox{.2\baselineskip}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}}\newline\noindent
    }{
        \newline\noindent {\rule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}}
    \end{Boxname}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{boxname}[Name of the Box]
        some stuff
    \end{boxname}
\end{document}
```

My problem: There is always this one dot I can't delete. Can some help me get rid of this dot?

Comment: Your example does not compile: there's few undefined control sequence errors. Could you complete it to make it compilable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a specific style where to remove punctuation and space after the heading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}

% The Box
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headpunct={},
  postheadspace=0pt,
]{box}
\declaretheorem[
  style=box,
  name = ,
  numbered = no,
]{Boxname}
\newenvironment{boxname}[1][]{%
  \begin{Boxname}
  \ifblank{#1}
    {\mbox{}}
    {\normalcolor\normalfont\textbf{#1}}%
  \\
  \raisebox{.2\baselineskip}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}}\\
}{%
  \\\rule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}
  \end{Boxname}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxname}[Name of the Box]
some stuff
\end{boxname}

\end{document}
```

I also simplified the code.

[image]

Comment: Uhm I don't know if it's intentional but I would expect that if someone says "no" to numbered, even the dot should be automatically removed. I hope it gets changed in newer releases. Yesterday I was going through the code but I missed the obvious `headpunct` :D

Comment: @Alenanno The heading is built from name, number, attribution, punctuation and spaces between them.

Comment: Sure, I was just expecting "numbered" to include the digit and the separator, as in `1.`.

Comment: @Alenanno Some styles want the number in front of the name.

Comment: That's not my point, I was referring to the fact that removing the number doesn't also remove the dot, which, when it's by itself, makes no sense.

Comment: @Alenanno There could still be the name. My point is that all items are independent of each other. Some styles don't want punctuation at all.

Comment: @Alenanno Using thmtools and creating thmboxes with S M or L style, there is no dot. Using thmtools with the "newer" styles, like blank style, there is the dot.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for that good answer. It fixed a big problem and you provided me a far better code!